# Acumatica GI - Inventory Transaction History Screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

I want to create a GI for Inventory Transaction History Screen (IN405000).

Since the table InventoryTranHistEnqResult isn't present in the database...few of the columns of this screen are taken from INTran Table.

I am not able to find following columns: BegQty, QtyIn, QtyOut, EndQty...

I also tried the following query on database to find these columns

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EndQty%'
```

The DAC for these fields is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfAdR.png)

Comment: You need to look at the DAC in the Acumatica to find out how it is built. It is better to search the source code for the fields and not bother looking at SQL for any fields. GI are built on the DAC and not specifically the SQL as the DAC could be a PXProjection or contain unbound/calculated fields.

Comment: I went through the DAC of these fields but couldn't find a solution.. the DAC for all these fields is

[PXDBQuantity()]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty. Out", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the information behind the page in the page Graph will give you the answers to your question. Inventory Transaction History Screen (IN405000) uses graph `InventoryTranHistEnq`. The grid in this page uses DAC `InventoryTranHistEnqResult` in the following view:

```
PXSelectJoin<InventoryTranHistEnqResult,
CrossJoin<INTran>,
Where<True, Equal<True>>,
OrderBy<Asc<InventoryTranHistEnqResult.gridLineNbr>>> ResultRecords
```

The `ResultsRecords` are built dynamically in the inquiry using the following:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable resultRecords()
{
    int startRow = PXView.StartRow;
    int totalRows = 0;
    decimal? beginQty = null;

    List<object> list = InternalResultRecords.View.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, new object[PXView.SortColumns.Length], PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows);
    PXView.StartRow = 0;

    foreach (PXResult<InventoryTranHistEnqResult> item in list)
    {
        InventoryTranHistEnqResult it = (InventoryTranHistEnqResult)item;
        it.BegQty = beginQty = (beginQty ?? it.BegQty);
        decimal? QtyIn = it.QtyIn;
        decimal? QtyOut = it.QtyOut;
        beginQty += (QtyIn ?? 0m) - (QtyOut ?? 0m);
        it.EndQty = beginQty;
    }
    return list;
}
```

So i guess the short answer is you cannot use the results of this page for a GI as it is built in the page only. You might want to look into adding what you need to this history page via a customization or make your own version of this page/graph/dac if the information you need is that important.

Comment: Okay...so i am trying to add a Customer column(https://stackoverflow.com/q/45742684/4405230)  in this screen that would show the customer ID related to the specific inventory...But again while adding data field during customization it says InventoryTranHistEnqResult table doesn't exists...So how can I add grid columns to this table?

Comment: Because it doesn't exist as an actual table you cannot add it. You need to add it to another table that does exist and join in your GI

Comment: What if I want to add a column in this Inventory Transaction History Screen? Since the table doesn't exist that cannot be done... Is there a way where I can add another table to this screen ?

Comment: you might be able to write a table extension (unbound) and override IEnumerable resultRecords() to add in your values

Comment: Okay...i'll try creating an unbound field